# How fast layout is drawn?

Tags: android, optimization, view, user-experience

How can one calculate how fast it takes for a specific layout to be drawn (From A-Z)? And.. Is there a possibility to calculate every part of layout building - measure, layout, draw.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you need profiling for layout? I'll start here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html